# Proof through combinatorial argument for $\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)(n-i) = \binom{n}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I am attempting to solve this counting problem through combinatorial argument. The following is the equation I am given:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)(n-i) = \binom{n}{3}$$

I understand that the right-hand side of this equation represents a set of $n$-elements out of which we choose 3. For example I believe we can say suppose we have a group of $n$ people and we want to choose 3 out of $n$ to be in a committee. However I'm not sure how to express the left-hand side in words. If forming a committee is an appropriate way to tackle this problem then I know the left-hand side must utilize the addition and multiplication principles, but I don't know how to put it into words. Also my intuition tells me that in solving this we should first flip $$(n-i)(i-1)$$

Thanks!

Comment: flipping is not needed. See my answer.

Comment: "flipping" is not needed.  But the flipped form certainly has more visual appeal.  i spends its time between n and 1 so why not put it between n and 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: split on the fact that the middle member (in sorted numerical order, the members are numbered $1$ to $n$) is $i$. Then we pick one from before and one from after.

Comment: Can you explain further ?

Comment: So basically what you're saying is for example we take n people or n objects and line them up and pick someone in the middle (i) and then there are i-1 choices for whatever was on the left of said object and n-i choices for whatever was on the right of said object?

Comment: Then, doesn't $i$ go from $2&-$n-1$ ?. If $i$ is either of the end points, then only one other number can be chosen.

Comment: We split the three person committees in disjoint sets $M_i$, which consists of all committees $a < b < c$ ($a,b,c \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$) with $b = i$. This is a partition of all committees, and so we have the sum. If we want to pick a committee in $M_i$, we are forced to take $b=i$ but we need exactly one member form $\{1,\ldots i-1\}$ and one from $\{i+1,\ldots,n\}$. Hence the product (2 independent choices).

Comment: The terms in the sum corresponding to $i=1$ and $i=n$ are indeed 0, as expected. So we can leave them in or leave them out, it does not matter.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you so much! I understand it now! :)

Comment: @KingTut Glad I could help. I hadn't seen it before.